# Mapping inputs to an array (A better way?)

Tags: c, embedded

I'm working in an embedded system and have "mapped" some defines to an array for inputs.

```
volatile int INPUT_ARRAY[40];


#define INPUT01 INPUT_ARRAY[0]
#define INPUT02 INPUT_ARRAY[1]


// section 2
if ( INPUT01 && INPUT02 ) {
  writepin(outputpin, value);
}
```

If I want to read from Input 1, I can simply say `newvariable = INPUT01` or I can compare data with Input 1, like in section 2 of my code. I'm not sure if this is a normal way of mapping the name INPUT01 to where the array position is. Or for an Input pin in the first place. Each array value represents a binary pin, and are read into the array by decoding a port value (16 bit). Question: Is using the defines and array like this reasonably efficient?

Comment: As this is efficient, most complilers are more then enough to inline simple `static inline int INPUT02(void) { return INPUT_ARRAY[0]; }` function. Such functions are nowadays preferred over macros, as they don't pollute the code so much and allow some obfuscating and more readability, which in the long run is way more valuable then efficiency.

Comment: What do you mean "mapped"? Memory-mapped? DMA? Manual copy? What? Of course this will be much slower than reading directly from the GPIO registers. In general, trying to be clever with some abstraction layer above plain GPIO rarely ends well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your solution is efficient.

Before the C compiler even sees your code, the C preprocessor substitutes `INPUT_ARRAY[0]` for `INPUT01` and, similarly, `INPUT_ARRAY[1]` for `INPUT02`; so this substitution uses zero time and zero power at run time.

Moreover, when the C compiler sees `INPUT_ARRAY[1]` in the preprocessed code, it adds 1 *at compile time* to the base address of `INPUT_ARRAY`. Therefore, you get maximal efficiency at run time.

Admittedly, were you manually to turn your C compiler's optimizer off, as with the `-O0` option of GCC, then it is conceivable that the compiler would emit assembly code to add the 1 at run time. So don't do that.

The only likely exception to the foregoing would be the case that the base address of `INPUT_ARRAY` were unknown to the compiler at run time, not likely because `INPUT_ARRAY` were dynamically allocated on the heap (which would make little sense for hardware device addressing), but likely because the base address of `INPUT_ARRAY` were configurable during boot via device configuration registers. Some hardware does this, but if yours does, why, that is exactly the reason your MCU (or MPU) possesses an index-offset indirect addressing mode in the first place. Though this mode engages the MCU's integer arithmetic unit, [a] the mode does not multiply (multiplication being a power-hungry operation); and, [b] anyway, the mode is such a normal, often-used mode that MCUs are invariably designed to support it efficiently—not perhaps as efficiently as precomputed direct addressing, but as efficiently as one can reasonably expect for such a use. The MCU's manufacturer knows that device pins are things you need to address. The engineer who designed your MCU will have given priority to making the index-offset indirect mode as efficient as possible for this and other reasons. (You could maybe still cheat the matter to save a few millijoules via self-modifying code, if your MCU even allowed that; but, as an engineer, you'd regret the cheat, I suspect, unless security and maintainability were non-issues to you. The problem probably is not much of a real problem. Index-offset indirect addressing is the normal technique when the base address remains unknown until run time. If you *really* need to save that last millijoule, then you might not be using a C compiler for your code's inner loop, anyway, but might be handcrafting assembly code.)

I suspect that you would find it instructive to tell your compiler to emit assembly code for your inspection. I do not know which compiler you are using but, if you were using GCC, then `gcc -S myfile.c`.